# What is the usage of dispatch in django class base view

Tags: python, django

Django `ListView` have a method `dispatch()`.  According to Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) dispatch is **The method that accepts a request argument plus arguments, and returns a HTTP response**. Have been searching for more information but couldn't find any neither can understand properly. Can anyone explain me a bit deeper for a better understanding.

Comment: Provided link is broken.

Comment: Updated the link.

Comment: What I understand is - it determines the request type and call the appropriate method for it. What I mean is if the request is `POST` then it calls the `POST` method inside the view class, if `GET` request then calls `GET` method.

Comment: dispatch is a middleman between requests and responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In django's class based view you write all your functionality inside methods based on http request verb names like

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #processing to be done in case of GET request on that particular url

def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #processing to be done in case of POST request on that particular url
```

and so on.

When a request arrives the dispatch method is called and tries to search for appropriate method to serve that request like defined get method in case of a GET request and if such a method does not exists inside that class it calls http_method_not_allowed.

So actually you don't usually have to override this method unless you have to do some preprocessing beforehand or you want all your requests to be routed to a method of your choice or you want to manually control this routing process.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a look at the code?

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Your urls.py entry will point to the class based view's as_view() method. As you will see that calls dispatch which basically tries to process the correct method depending on how the view is configured - usually the get() method in the case if a ListView.